# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
{Data.map(datas => <Col lg={4}>
    <PriceCard key={datas.id}  title={datas.title}  text={datas.text}  price1={datas.price1} price1text={datas.price1text} price2={datas.price2} price2text={datas.price2text} price3={datas.price3} price3text={datas.price3text} price4={datas.price4} price4text={datas.price4text} price5={datas.price5} price5text={datas.price5text}  imgUrl={datas.imgUrl} />
</Col>)}
```

And I get his error, but I have unique key.

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

Comment: I think you should assign `key` to `<Col >` as well.
Basically the parent component inside the map should have a `key` prop

Comment: The `<Col>` components are the children in the list, they are the ones that should have the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Col` should have a key as well. Try doing this:

{Data.map((datas, index) => <Col lg={4} **key={index}**  >)}

Comment: oh okay  i add "rowkey" to my data and there is no error anymore but key={index} didn't work